# Problem in implementing hardcoded Auth in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I want to implement a hardcoded auth in reactjs, i.e., if user enters a particular string then access is given otherwise not.
My app.js code is as follows:

```
function App() {

    const[user, setUser]= useState(false);
    const[ID, setID]= useState('');
    const[IDError, setIDError]= useState('');

    const clearErrors = () =>{
        setIDError('');
    }


    const handleLogin=()=>{
        clearErrors();
        if(ID==="quantel123"){
            setUser(true);
        }else if(ID===""){
            setIDError("This field can't be empty. Access denied!");
        }else{
            setIDError("The ID entered is wrong");
        }
    };

    const handleLogout=()=>{
        if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to Logout?')){
            setUser(false);
        }
    };

    useEffect(()=>{
        const authListener=()=>{
            if(user){
                setUser(user);
            }else{
                setUser(false);
            }
           
        };

        authListener();
    }, [user]);

  
  return (
    <Router>
    {user?(
        <Grid container direction="column">
            <Grid item>
                <Navbar />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item container>
                <Grid item xs={false} sm={2}>
                    <Sidebar handleLogout={handleLogout} />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={10}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/login"><Redirect to="/" /></Route>  
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                        <Route exact path="/Bookings" component={EnhancedBookingTable}/>
                        <Route component={Error}/>
                    </Switch>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid> 
    ):(
        <>
            <Redirect to="/login" />
            <Route exact path="/login" render={(props)=>(
                <Login {...props}
                    ID={ID}
                    setID={setID}
                    handleLogin={handleLogin}
                    IDError={IDError}
                    setIDError={setIDError}
                />
            )}/>
        </>
    )}
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The Hardcoded auth is working fine. But there is only one problem, i.e., whenever the page is refreshed, the user gets logged out. This is because the setUser value is initialized to false on every re-ender. How to handle this??

Comment: Persist your state to localStorage, read it in when the component mounts and initialize your state accordingly. If you need an example I can provide one.

Comment: Yes! Example will be good as I am new to reactjs

Comment: Is it related to redux?

Comment: No, localStorage is unrelated to Redux, but Redux state is often persisted to localStorage/persistent storage. Does a solution for you need to be related to Redux?

Comment: No! I was just confused because redux also cretaes a local storage to save states. Am I right?

Comment: No, Redux is all in-memory, you reload the page it goes away, similar to your local component state.

Answer (score 0):

React state exists only in memory, when you reload the page it is reset from scratch. You can use localStorage to persist your user state.

```
// state initializer function
const [user, setUser] = useState(() => {
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem("auth");
  return JSON.parse(loggedIn) ?? false;
});

// persist state to local storage on updates
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("auth", JSON.stringify(user));
}, [user]);
```

## Demo

[image: Edit problem-in-implementing-hardcoded-auth-in-reactjs]